# Dot formatting in Python with list

Tags: python, list

I want to know if its possible to decrypt a list and use in dot formatting:

Eg as below:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]

str1 = "{}{}{}".format(list1)
```

What should I do to pick each elements from list1 and use in dot formatting?

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]

str1 = "{}{}{}".format(list1.items())
```

Comment: `.format(*list1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list1` is already the sequence of values you need. What you are missing is the syntax to unpack the list and provide each element as a separate argument to `str.format`:

```
str1 = "{}{}{}".format(*list1)
```

Alternatively, you can pass the list as a single argument and let the format string extract the desired elements:

```
str1 = "{0[0]}{0[1]}{0[2]}".format(list1)
```

(You need to be explicit about each replacement field extracting from argument 0, though, so this is a fairly verbose option.)

For this particular format string and list, though, you could simply use `str.join`:

```
str1 = "".join(list1)
```

Comment: The `.format()` version will work if the list contains non-string values, `join()` only works with strings.

Comment: True, it's not just the format string, but the values to format, that let `''.join` be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is probably overly simple because you wouldn't need format at all to simply concatenate all the items.   `''.join(list1)` would do the job.

If your format is more complex/irregular but you always have the same number of items in the list, you can use the format method with unpacking:

```
"{} : {} ... {}".format(*list1)

'a : b ... c'
```

If your list doesn't alway have the same length and the format is more elaborate than just the values themselves, you can map the format function over the items in the list and use join to combine the resulting strings.

For example:

```
list1 = [ 1, 2.3, 45.6, 7.89 ]

string1 = " ".join(map("{0:5.2f}".format,list1))

' 1.00  2.30 45.60  7.89'
```